# The so-called error function defined as: $\operatorname{erf}(x)=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_0^xe^{-t^{2}}dt$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, error-function

The so-called error function is defined as:

$$\operatorname{erf}(x)=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_0^xe^{-t^{2}}dt$$

show that the function $y(x) = e^{x^2}\operatorname{erf}(x)$ satisfies the differential equation:

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=2xy+\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}$$

I have no idea how to start if someone could show me that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Don't you just take the derivative of $y$ and compare it to $2xy$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using the formula $(uv)'=u'v+uv'$, you just have (prime = diff. with respect to x). 
$$
\left(e^{x^2}\times\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_0^{{x}}e^{-t^{2}}dt\right)'=2xe^{x^2}\left(\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_0^{{x}}e^{-t^{2}}dt\right)+\left(e^{x^2}\times\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}e^{-x^{2}}\right)=2xy+\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}
$$ since
$$
\left(\int_0^{{x}}e^{-t^{2}}dt\right)'=e^{-x^{2}}.
$$